# EF 4.0: Best way to append new data

Tags: entity-framework

I'm sorry for the hard-to-understand title!

What i'm trying is very simple, i have these tables :

```
Maintable(ID) 
Child1(MainTableID, ID)
Child2(MainTableID, ID)
Child3(MainTableID, ID)
Child4(MainTableID, ID)
```

Child2, Child3, and Child4 are created from Child1, so i recreate them everytime Maintable or Child1 is changed :

```
Child2 = GetChild2FromChild1()
Child3 = GetChild3FromChild1()
Child4 = GetChild4FromChild1()
```

After that, i just simply delete the old tables, and save the newly created :

```
using (var context = new EF())
{
    context.DeleteObject(child2); // only the ones belong to Maintable 
    context.DeleteObject(child3);   
    context.DeleteObject(child4);
}       

using (var context = new EF())
{
    // because i always delete child2->4 , so i always set their state to be Added 
    // here i will add the new tables, something like this :  
    foreach (var child2 in Maintable.child2)
    {
        counterID--;
        child2.State = State.Added;
        child2.ID = counterID;
    }


    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I know it's hard to understand, so here are the steps :

- The entity `Maintable` contains four child tables (1->4)
- Everytime i need to update entity `Maintable`, i will have to delete : Maintable.Child2,  Maintable.Child3, Maintable.Child4, except Child1
- Then i will append the new data to Child2, Child3, Child4

But this solution is really a pain in the ass, i keep getting errors that i hardly figure out why, and strange results etc, for instance i've waited an afternoon debugging without any positive progress before posting this question !

So what i want to ask is is there another way which would meet my needs but also a "clean" one, because i think my problem is not very complicated, and i'm not very familiar with C#

Comment: It might be me but I didn't understand a thing from what you are asking. It might be the case with other people as well, consider revising your question.

Comment: Are you trying to add new rows? or update the rows? your question is actually not so clear :/

Comment: here when you use `using(var context = new EF())`, in first one you delete objects but since you don't save it in your second `using` scope they won't be deleted.

Comment: @Null : This is a better elaborated version of my question, please take a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800089/ef-4-0-confusing-in-handling-foreign-tables

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can understand you are actually just editing the `ID` of child2-3-4. If I got you right this is the way to go when updating.

```
using (var context = new EF())
{  
    foreach (var child2 in Maintable.child2)
    {
        counterID--; 
        child2.ID = counterID;
    }

    foreach (var child3 in Maintable.child3)
    {
        counterID--; 
        child3 .ID = counterID;
    }

    foreach (var child4 in Maintable.child4)
    {
        counterID--; 
        child4 .ID = counterID;
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

But I doubt this is what you ask :/

Comment: This is a better elaborated version of my question, please take a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800089/ef-4-0-confusing-in-handling-foreign-tables