# C# & EF 4.0: confusing in handling foreign tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm very sorry for the title, can't figure out a better one. Any amendment is greatly appreciated!

Says i have these tables :

```
Header(id int identity(1,1), Date datetime, ...) 

Detail(id int identity(1,1), HeaderID int, MaterialID nvarchar(24), Quantity float, AccountID nvarchar(20), Amount float)

Ledger(HeaderID, AccountID nvarchar(20), Amount float) 

InventoryTransactionDetail(HeaderID, MaterialID nvarchar(24), Quantity float)
```

Here is how this work :

- Header contains general information of a voucher
- Detail contains voucher's detail records
- We will then analyze Detail's record and produce data for Ledger and Inventory

For example :

```
Insert into Header(Date, ...) values (getdate(), ...)

Assuming the newly created header ID is 1 

Insert into Detail(HeaderID, MaterialID, Quantity, AccountID, Amount) 
    values(1, 'MAT1', 50, '1561', 500000)

After analyzing, we have Ledger and InventoryTransactionDetail's records: 

Insert into Ledger(HeaderID, AccountID, Amount) 
    values(1, '1561', 500000)

Insert into InventoryTransactionDetail(HeaderID, MaterialID, Quantity) 
    values(1, 'MAT1', 50)
```

So if there is any changes was made on the voucher, i will :

- Update the header and the detail
- Delete from Ledger and Inventory, and insert new analyzed records into them

Sound simple, right? I can achieve this using T-sql in just a glance, but doing this using EF is giving me a nightmare, i keep getting errors i can't figure out why and how to fix it!

So what i want to ask is, am i doing this the right way?

By the way, this is one of the errors i'm getting :

> A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property
>   values that define the referential constraints are not consistent
>   between principal and dependent objects in the relationship.

Line of error (the line before the last : Attach(VH) ) :

```
    using (var context2 = new GModel())
    {
        List<Ledger> AJToCheck = (from a in context2.Ledger where a.VHID == VH.ID select a).ToList();
        foreach (Ledger DetailToCheck in AJToCheck)
        {
            context2.DeleteObject(DetailToCheck);
        }

        List<ITDetail> ITToCheck = (from a in context2.ITDetail where a.VHID == VH.ID select a).ToList();
        foreach (ITDetail DetailToCheck in ITToCheck)
        {
            context2.DeleteObject(DetailToCheck);
        }

        context2.SaveChanges();
    }

    using (var context = new GModel())
    {
        if (VH.ID == 0 || VH.ID == null)
        {
            VH.State = State.Added;
            context.VoucherHeader.AddObject(VH);
        }
        else
        {
            VH.State = State.Modified;

            int counterID = -1;

            foreach (var voucherDetail in VH.VoucherDetail)
            {
                if (voucherDetail.ID == 0)
                {
                    counterID--;
                    voucherDetail.State = State.Added;
                    voucherDetail.ID = counterID;
                }
                else voucherDetail.State = State.Modified; 
            }

            counterID = -1;

            foreach (var Ledger in VH.Ledger)
            {
                counterID--;
                Ledger.State = State.Added;
                Ledger.ID = counterID;
            }

            counterID = -1;

            foreach (var itDetail in VH.ITDetail)
            {
                counterID--;
                itDetail.State = State.Added;
                itDetail.ID = counterID;
            }

            context.VoucherHeader.Attach(VH);
            context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(VH, StateHelpers.GetEquivalentEntityState(VH.State));
```

Comment: I cannot wrap my head around it, did you solve it?

Comment: @Null in which part you are confused? I'll try to elaborate it better

Comment: The error is telling you that there is a foreign key that is not being altered correctly. Do your foreign key constraints cascade changes? Are you changes an adding/removing an object from a collection with updating the foreign depend? Or, are you adding an object that has had its foreign depend previously deleted?

Comment: Please specify where/how did you get "VH", because you are testing if it is new or not, and you are using 2 instances of context. Why do you check if object is new, and only set Id to -1, why not check other properties and navigations as roydukkey suggested, there could be an error also. I think that this is problem of inconsistent data between two contexts.

Comment: Hello? This has gone very quiet... Decrementing Id is quite odd, but I think it's a typo. As it's a voucher, I think the intention is to decrement the voucher usage count.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be much more complex than it needs to.

This error generally occurs when the entity in the many part of a one to many relationship is being attached with a foreign key different from the parent object.

In your case the SQL examples you show, you insert into the dependent tables and only set the hearderID, but in all your EF examples you assign negative numbers to the ID properties of all your navigation properties?

To repeat what you have with SQL you would be better off just going straight to the attach of your VH rather than attempting to manipulate the navigation properties.

When VH is attached, any of the navigation properties in the graph that didn't exist (IDs == 0) will be automatically added (inserted). Your marking both the VH and its navigation properties as modified is unnecessary, and likely contributes to your problem.

Try this instead:

```
    if (VH.ID == 0 || VH.ID == null)
    {
        VH.State = State.Added;
        context.VoucherHeader.AddObject(VH);
    }
    else
    {
        VH.State = State.Modified;
        context.VoucherHeader.Attach(VH);
        context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(VH, StateHelpers.GetEquivalentEntityState(VH.State));
    }
```

Also take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx for that version of EF

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but may be you didn't get what i mean !

Comment: I thought you meant direct SQL inserts work, but not the ef sample code you sent? But your sample ef code isn't doing what your sample SQL is.

Comment: Have you tried this and found it doesn't work? Have you ran SQL profiler and examined the SQL EF is generating?

Comment: since your answer did not solve the problem directly, but it gave me some thoughts to go on, and you're the one who tried best to help me, and i'm greatly appreciated of your helps, so i will award the bounty to you, because it's not going back to me anyway

Comment: Thanks! Have you considered upgrading to EF6? There are quite a number of improvements, particularly since the introduction of DbContext